# When should a company hire an Adwords specialist?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I am working for a quite large fashion label that went online with its new online shops a few months ago. Actually we have the Google Analytics and shop development inhouse, but the Adwords campaigns are made by an agency.

I am quite new into this company and did not know that there is a working setup like this. And tbh I am not sure if it is working - so I am looking for more information about how Google Analytics and Google Adwords should work together.

As far as I know this agency has sent us no GA implementation requirements. They just get the really basic GA stuff including a tracked checkout process.

I am not deep into GA & Adwords but as far as I know it is best when this is made by one and the same person/team. Especially when you have quite large budgets and visit counts on your shop (while conversion kinda sucks). Because actually we do not know exactly what they are doing and even if we get some GA lessons, I doubt that you can split these online marketing parts like that.

I hope this question is clear and fits to ProMasters.

Comment: "while conversation kinda sucks" - I guess that should be "conversion"? (Unless you really don't like talking to your colleagues?! :)

Comment: Analytics does give more information - though with just adwords one can see quite a bit of data, including - impressions, cost, ctr, conversions etc etc. The adwords might already be linked with analytics - look in account access/linked accounts. As for whether they should be monitoring analytics too - depends on their job spec.

Comment: So you think GA Analytic & Adwords should be handled in one team and not separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better you go in the reverse order. Connect with your In house Analytics team to get all the Adwords details in Google analytics. You can track all the important Adwords details in Google analytics.

Now hire an Adwords specialist and tell him to work along with agency so that he will understand all the things which are happening. Once he confident about your domain and Adwords you can bring campaigns to In house.

Let me know if you have any clarifications.
Thanks,
Sathya

Comment: That is what I think we should do and that was exactly my question. Because I really think we need an inhouse specialist for AdWords.

Comment: My suggestion -  It's right time to hire a specialist. Go for it without much thinking..All the best